# Select Box Validation if Option Text Contains Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

If I have a select box, with the text Select (Insert Type of Addon)

For example, with the text "Select Case and Clip" as the default option as well as 5 other select boxes, I want to validate this form only if no select box contains the word "Select" in it.

This is using Virtuemart, and there is no way to make sure the options are selected properly.

My idea, would be to use the method above and find the value Select in an options text, on submission

```
 <select name="customPrice[0][27]" id="customPrice027">
     <option value="265">Select Case &amp; Clip</option>
     <option value="266">$25.00 - Black - Large - 1</option>
     <option value="267">$0.00 - Black - None - 2</option>
     <option value="268">$10.00 - Beige - Small - 3</option>
     <option value="269">$20.00 - Beige - Large - 4</option>
     <option value="270">$0.00 - Beige - None - 5</option>
     <option value="271">$10.00 - Blue - Small - 6</option>
     <option value="272">$20.00 - Blue - Large - 7</option>
     <option value="273">$0.00 - Blue - None - 8</option>
     <option value="274">$10.00 - Gray - Small - 9</option>
     <option value="275">$20.00 - Gray - Large - A</option>
     <option value="276">$0.00 - Gray - None - B</option>
     <option value="277">$20.00 - Red - Large - R</option>
     <option value="278">$20.00 - Olive Drab - Large - D</option>
 </select>
```

My issue is that this is dynamically generated, so I cannot validate and have the first option contain a 0 value.

I think using regEx may be the way to go to find the word "Select" in my post.

Apologize if this is stupid (I am a beginner with jQuery).

Here is my code below, trying to just add a console message saying there is a Select box, with text containing "Select"

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

       if ($("select").indexOf("Select") >= 1) {
          console.log('Select is Selected');
       }       

    });
```

Any pointers here? I'd also like this to also validate upon submit button press, before allowing it to do so.

### Update:

My code is dependent and has to stop the form submission, on selection of the button. I know the ID, Type, Name, Title and Value of the submission button (pre-defined)

This is one out of 6 boxes, all same condition fits and triggers this message.

Here is my code, it isn't stopping on submit. I can send a link in private message if need be for the site example.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

       $( ".addtocart-button" ).click(function() {

        if($("option:contains('Select')").length){
           event.preventDefault();
           console.log("Select found");
        }


    });
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    if($("#customPrice027 option:selected:contains('Select')").length){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert("found");
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/QcEbL/1/

**Modified to work with your provided code**

```
$( ".addtocart-button" ).click(function(e) {

    if($("#customPrice027 option:selected:contains('Select')").length){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log("Select found");
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/QcEbL/2/

Comment: This works to detect the select value, so this is fine. Look at my updated post in just a minute, and see the code I am using, and added notes to my new issue.

Comment: @JustinBevan I have updated my code to work fire on the submit of a form and prevent the submit if `Select` is detected.

Comment: This works great! Just need to change the action after it's detected, but it worked just as needed. I assume this works on any form on the page, so if two forms were to be on a page together, it would trigger for both correct? I changed the selected condition to use "select option:selected:contains('select');" to target all select boxes.

Comment: The first example would work on any form, I have provided a more specific example below the first example.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks again! You were a great help and I definitely learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why use the `option text` to find a select word in the select box if you can do that using the `value`

```
$('#sub').on('click', function() { 
   var selectval = $('#customPrice027').val();
   if(selectval == '265') { 
      alert("Gotcha!");
   }
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nesmar/yXbP4/1/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not work, the value of the first field is dynamic based on a database ID, so this is different for each option. This was an example, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would like the user to select something other than the default value, if so check the text of the selected option

```
var valid = true;

$('select').each(function() {
    if ($('option:selected', this).text().indexOf('Select') != -1) valid = false;
    return valid;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTe3u/1/)